# ASP.NET Core DateTime filter changes format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, asp.net-core

I'm developing an ASP.Net Core application with some filters in a paged list, like so:

[image: Date Filter example]

Whenever I press "Procurar", the code works just fine for the first list, displaying this URL:

```
https://localhost:44314/?estadoFilter=&initialDate=2020-06-10T11%3A22&endDate=2020-07-10&SearchString=
```

However when I change to another page back and forth, the URL changes between these two:

```
https://localhost:44314/?pageNumber=1&initialDate=10%2F06%2F2020%2011%3A22%3A00&endDate=10%2F07%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00
https://localhost:44314/?pageNumber=1&initialDate=06%2F10%2F2020%2011%3A22%3A00&endDate=07%2F10%2F2020%2000%3A00%3A00
```

The only difference being that the day and month keep changing formats. I have tried to change the ViewModel's data annotations but none of these works:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime initialDate { get; set; }
```

The app just continues to switch back between format whenever a new view is loaded. Any thoughts on why the framework keeps changing formats?

Comment: Can you provide us some codes that can reproduce your problem?